# read a String from the Channelbuffer

Tags: java

I am sendung a String to the server via Socket. I implemented the TCPClient class to simulate a real scenario. The message starts always with `#` and ends with `##`. Everything in between are information. I just trying to read the ASCii characters when receiving the stream inside the `decodeMessage()`. So when reading the first byte which contains `35` Ascci code, then I want to search the buffer for the end the message `##` which are 3535 in ASCCII table.

How can I read the message from the buffer?

**Client**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.Socket;


public class TCPClient {

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {

        String message;
        String result;
        String aString = "#201601140000006#13534035454#1#0000#AUT#2#0000050000020027#114.034407,E,22.648272,N,,0.00,0.00#010104#004500#114.034407,E,22.648272,N,0.00,0.00#010104#004500##";
        // String aString = "###";
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(aString));

        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 39537);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        message = inFromUser.readLine();
        outToServer.writeBytes(message + '\n');
        result = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println(result);
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

**docodeMessage()**

```
private Object decodeMessage(final ChannelBuffer buffer) {
    // Here with my String I am getting 160 for readableBytes.
    int readableBytes = buffer.readableBytes();
    if (readableBytes < 5) {
       //incase the messagejust contains ### also begining and end.
        return null;
    }

    if (readableBytes >= 5) {
        boolean messageStart = false;
        int indexMessageBegin;
        for (int i = 0; i < readableBytes; i++) {
            int readerIndex = buffer.readerIndex() + i;
            if (buffer.getByte(readerIndex) == 35) { // Message begin.
                messageStart = true;
                indexMessageBegin = i;
            }
            if (messageStart) {
                if (buffer.getByte(i) == 35 && buffer.getByte(i + 1) == 35) {
                    messageStart = false;
                    // when reading the message I want to cut it out from the stream
                    byte[] decoded = new byte[0x00 + i];
                }
            }

        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can't you read everything then parse?

Comment: @RC.: I am getting the String as ASCII characters inside the docode() and when I am doing the following buffer.getByte(0) I am getting `35`.